# Write math papers using \doublespacing?

Tags: soft-question, notation, proof-writing, article-writing

Or keep math papers single-spaced?

Single-spacing seems to keep important information together a little bit better, e.g., theorems and its proofs.  While double-spacing is visually a little more comfortable to read, information such as theorems and its proofs are separated frequently, although during somewhat-lengthy discussion sections of a paper, double-spacing would be very nice for a reader.

What do you think?  Is there a standard convention among math writers?

Comment: If you are submitting to a journal you have no choice. It's up to the journal's style editors.

Comment: You say "double-spacing is visually a little more comfortable to read". I think that is a personal opinion.

Comment: Single spacing is definitely the standard. Have you ever seen a published book or paper with double spacing? (Except perhaps for some PhD theses where the university style enforces double spacing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do is use `\vspace` whenever I need vertical space. If I find myself using it all the time, I might use doublespacing. Normally, I find that `\vspace` is sufficient.